# Poor Resolution Video ".MOV"

Tags: video-editor

Yesterday, I'd been editing a film for work. I imported the footage from my camera and the clips looked perfectly fine. So I uploaded the clips to Google Drive and then downloaded on my computer and imported these footages to my Linux machine using KDENLive editor. The footage looks all pixelated and it has terrible resolution.

Is there something I can do to fix it? I tried using Handbrake to convert it to another format but even that didn't work.

Comment: Welcome to Video Production SE! A MediaInfo (http://mediaarea.net/en/MediaInfo) output of the file would be very helpful.

Comment: A screenshot of the pixelated version would also be helpful.

Comment: Well, I'll try my best to provide more information but really it's just as it sounds. Literally, it's un-watchable. On iMovie it was HD. Which is strange considering it's the same clip just on a different machine.

Comment: @user280902 - yeah, but there are multiple things that can cause that kind of an issue.  We can't recognize what the actual problem is from your description.  But visually, we may be able to recognize it, particularly with the details of the actual video file provided.

Comment: Also, how did you export it out of iMovie? Which share settings did you use?

Answer (score 2):

It was my own fault -- when I had exported it, I didn't make sure to export it in full resolution because since it already was, I thought that step was automatic.

Comment: Glad you found it, thanks for posting the solution.